Whirlpool Stove bottom coil not heating
Recently my Whirlpool Stove/Oven has been messing up. I.E. The bottom coil (I think that’s what it’s called) has not been heating up, not sure what part to order because i can’t find the manual anywhere :( if someone knows a solution aside from buying the part please help !!!

Assuming that the top element ("broil") works, it is quite likely that the element itself is what failed. They are usually fairly easy to replace.
Turn off the breaker first! I would not rely on the oven controls to safely shut off all possibly "hot" wires connected to or near the elements.
Remove the element - usually a couple of screws and some sort of plug-in wire harness/connector. If you can check the resistance that would be great. Typical is in the 20 to 40 Ohm range. If it shows very high (or "infinite") resistance then it is broken.
Once you find the oven model # - it should be somewhere on the oven - you can order a replacement. The replacement doesn't have to be from Whirlpool but it does have to be designed to match the original resistance, physical size and electrical connection.

Just to note, some ranges have cabinet parts covering the bake element—or even the element connectors—so a little more disassembly may be required.  Example: https://youtu.be/3T5D2Nc9hVg?si=O_43-wjsU7tif8A2

Always check for voltage before working on the device even after turning off the breaker. It's a quick check that could save your life if the wiring is not as assumed.


not sure what part to order

Look up online parts list for your stove. Most online parts ordering sites have parts diagrams available.
The part is likely called "lower heating element" or "lower heater".
You'll need the model number of the stove. Look for a label somewhere on the outside of the chamber, i.e. around the front seal, around the periphery of the door (inside and/or sides of a thick door).

I can’t find the manual anywhere

That would not be helpful as most manuals today don't have part list diagrams AFAIK.

if someone knows a solution aside from buying the part please help

Most likely buying the part is the solution.
It is possible that the socket where the heating element plugs into has burned out. That's easy to check - remove the heating element and look at the contacts of the socket. You can edit your question and update it by adding a clear zoomed-in photo of the socket. You can upload the photo directly into the question from a .jpg file on your computer, or on your mobile device.
